# Inserting Blank Rows while Appending

Tags: r

I have two tables which i have written into excel using write.table using append argument but these two table are coming one by one but I want them to come leaving one or two blank rows between them.
I am using this command:

```
write.table(df1, file = "filename.csv",sep = ", ",row.names=FALSE,append=TRUE)
write.table(df2, file = "filename.csv",sep = ", ",row.names=FALSE,append=TRUE)
```

How are they coming:

```
Gender  Col1 Col2
Male    18  13
Female  3   3   
Grids   Col1 Col2
6 to 12     2   0
12 to 24    6   6
```

How I want them to append:

```
Gender  Col1    Col2
Male    18  13
Female  3   3

Grids     Col1  Col2
6 to 12     2   0
12 to 24    6   6
```

i.e. to have space of blank rows in between. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a row in the first dataset

```
df1 <- rbind(df1, setNames(replicate(3, "", simplify = FALSE), names(df1)))
```

and then do the `write.table`

```
write.table(df1, file = "filename.csv",sep = ", ",row.names=FALSE,append=TRUE, quote = FALSE)
write.table(df2, file = "filename.csv",sep = ", ",row.names=FALSE,append=TRUE, quote = FALSE)
```

The output we get in opening the file is

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am a beginner in R so can you please tell me what is the function of setNames and what does the parameters given inside does? What does that "3" mean?

Comment: @PraveenSingh  setNames is used to name the `list`.  We wanted to have the same number of columns as in `df1`  so I used `3`, instead it can be `ncol(df1)`

Comment: Following error is coming in my system on typing the command.  Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated.

Comment: @PraveenSingh  which command got the error.  Okay, you have `factor` class for the column.  Convert it to `character` and it should be fine ie. `df1$Gender <- as.character(df1$Gender)` and then do the `rbind`